# gRPC c++ v1.38 async-server crashes

Tags: c++, asynchronous, grpc

I am new to gRPC. I am trying to follow the [example code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.38.x/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc) (we have to use version gRPC v1.38), to implement an asynchronous gRPC server with extra complexity in that the server will send multiple responses (aka,  stream) to gRPC client.

The proto is something like:

```
rpc  MyRequest (ReqMsg) returns (stream RespMsg)
```

Basically, when the gRPC server receive client request, it needs *asynchronously* get the info from somewhere else. When the required info comes back (via callback from a different thread, but multiple times), the callback function then *write back* the response using the data structure maintained in `CallData`, aka, responder ,etc.

During my testing, my gRPC server crashes at `proto_buffer_writer.h assertion failed !byte_buffer->Valid()` after writing back 2 or 3 responses. I am wondering whether it is due to diff thread (other than the thread which block-waiting on gRPC communication) is doing the writing.

Comment: please show us your code

Comment: I'm betting you are trying read some data which are not set by sender. You should check first if given value exist. Since protobuf3 all fields are optional. It is impossible to say more, since you didn't provide enough information (code).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved. The cause of the crash is that when sending back multiple responses (aka, streaming), my server doesn't wait for the token to be available before sending a new response.

Comment: This is weird. How you can send multiple responses? gRpc generates C++ code where you have to implement Service interfere and I do not see room for multiple responses. Or you have omitted important information in your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).